# Is there a faster way of evaluating every combination of booleans in an if statement in python?

Tags: python, if-statement, boolean-expression

If I have 4 booleans e.g

`if ((a(x) == True) and (b(x) == True) and (c(x) == True) and (d(x) == True)`

then I want to do something different for each combination including when only 3 of them are true (including which ones), 2..., then only each 1... etc...

Is there a quicker way than writing a bunch of elifs?

Possibly using a loop

Comment: Or do I have to write it 4! times?

Comment: I don't care about the order

Comment: There are 2^4 = 16 Boolean combinations rather than 4!. If you really have 16 cases then you have 16 cases. In addition to using a lot of elifs you can look into using Python's new `match ... case` construct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution with the lookup table is great but if you wanted to do something that takes less memory and around the same speed. You can use the if statement results to build on each other this way you'd only have 2^4(16) cases i.e:

```
if (a(x)):
    if(b(x):
        if(c(x)):
            if(d(x)):
                #do x
            else:
                #do y
        else:
            if (d(x)):
                #do z
            else:
                #do w
         #...
```

Comment: What if `d(x)` is expensive to call? What if we need to evaluate all of them at least once?

Answer (score 2):

You could build a lookup table using a `dict`:

```
lookup = {(True, True, True, True): func_1,
          (True, True, True, False): func_2,
          (True, True, False, True): func_3,
          ... etc.
         }
func = lookup[a(x), b(x), c(x), d(x)]
func()
```

Comment: how would I use this to e.g add an integer to a(x) if only a(x) were true?

Comment: @Primo4151 what would the `tuple` be if only `a(x)` were `True`?

Answer (score 0):

You can count the number of True booleans using arithmetic operators

```py
numTrue = (a(x) == True) + (b(x) == True) + (c(x) == True) + (d(x) == True)
if numTrue==4:
    # foo
elif numTrue==3:
    # bar
elif numTrue==2:
    # ...
elif numTrue==1:
    #...
else:
    # ...
```

Note that I kept your redundant structure `x==True`, which, from a boolean point a view is just a convoluted version of `x`. But at least, now, I am sure that your booleans (since I know nothing of `a(x)` and others) are `True` or `False`, not other truthiness are falseness.

Comment: but depending on the combination I want it to do something different. so a(x) being true does something different to b(x) being true

Comment: @Primo4151  Oh. Then you need to be more specific. Because from a generic point of view, we can't advise you nothing more that good old nested `if/else` statements.

Comment: @Primo4151 so then you have 4! different things that are different? What goes inside of each `if/else` statement to parse out the different instructions?

Comment: so if a(x) == True then it will execute a function where one of the parameters changes to a(x). If it was b(x) == True, it would execute the same function but instead of a(x), it would include b(x). If multiple are true, then I add the same function but with different _(x) getting executed

Answer (score 0):

> including when only 3 of them are true

This suggests you'd like to know that N of the 4 values are true:

```
vals = a(x), b(x), c(x), d(x)
num_true = sum(map(bool, vals))
```

---

Given such a vector of booleans, there are `2 ** 4 == 16` possibilities.
We can put 16 values into a `dict` named `d` and go from there.

```
k = " ".join(map(str, map(int, map(bool, vals))))
print(d[k])
```

---

If the identities don't matter to you,
then sort so we have fewer than 16 possibilities:

```
k = " ".join(sorted(map(str, map(int, map(bool, vals)))))
```